# does the FROM directive in a dockerfile allways pull the latest version of an image

Tags: docker

If I have a Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu/latest
```

and ubuntu update their image in the public registry. When I run `docker build .`, will it use the ubuntu that it got the first time or will it pull the new version?

Comment: I guess the latest, but a test is easy in order to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not.  A `FROM` directive will use whatever happens to be available in your local image cache, unless you pass `--pull` to `docker build`.